# How to fill sequence in Excel from ranges given in another sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel sheet where two columns (say `J` and `K`) among data in sheet1 are as follows:

> J ------------ K
>
> 1 ----------- 25
>
> 26 --------- 50
>
> 101 ------ 150

Which are some ranges. I have another sheet where I have column (let's say `I`), which I want to update it to have the values as indicated by the range; i.e. column values of `I` to be `1,2,3,...25,26,27,...50,101,102,103,...150` (vertically). Note that ranges in J-K are not always continuous (e.g. gap between `50` and `101`) and not always in the right order.

I'm trying to find some automated way to achieve that, instead of manually copying the starting value of the range (from `I`) and then dragging down sequentially until the ending value (from `J`) for every individual `I` and `J` value, which is a very huge set of data. Is there any way to help doing that?

Note: I'm using Microsoft Excel 2013, but a solution for excel 2010 or 2007 is more than welcomed...

Comment: I'd start with `private sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)`

Comment: Depending on how structured the data in Sheet1 is, you could solve this by using a formula. Is there a limit on the number of rows in Sheet1? Is there a limit on how many rows should be "generated" at maximum? Especially if you can answer the first question with "yes", there's a good chance a formula can be found.

Comment: @HaukeP. Actually it's fixed data, the ranges are the sequence of printed documents serial. It's fixed rows of what actually was printed, which isn't always have mathematical pattern. Did I get you right?

Comment: Ah, do you really need Excel to solve this? I guess, a simple piece of JavaScript code would do the job way better. (Or "just" VBA as well.)

Comment: @HaukeP. The data was submitted to me in Excel, plus there's some other stuff in the sheets that requires Excel. As a quick and dirty solution (to get my boss out of my head) I used a python script to do that after migrating the data to raw text file. But still interested in a way to do that without having to copy-paste a lot of data...

Comment: I posted a VBA solution that writes the data into a sheet below. Or do you really need a clever combination of worksheet functions to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

This macro should do it:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FillSequence()
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim SrcCol As Long
    Dim SrcRow As Long

    SrcCol = 10
    SrcRow = 1

    While Not IsEmpty(SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, SrcCol))
        Dim StartNumber As Long
        Dim EndNumber As Long

        StartNumber = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, SrcCol)
        EndNumber = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, SrcCol + 1)

        If EndNumber < StartNumber Then
            MsgBox "Input data wrong."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim Number As Long

        For Number = StartNumber To EndNumber
            ActiveCell = Number
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select ' This part could be optimized so
                                           ' that the selection does not have
                                           ' to be updated each time - but 
                                           ' this should suffice for the 
                                           ' moment. Just let me know if the
                                           ' performance is too bad for
                                           ' practical use.
        Next

        SrcRow = SrcRow + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

It assumes that your numbers are on Sheet1 in columns J and K (or 10 and 11) and start in the first row. Simply run it while having selected the first cell where the sequence should start. HTH.